# Type issues with using history.goBack() with react-router

Tags: typescript, react-router

I've become stuck on a problem where I cannot pass a function as a path to the react-router { Link } component.

Basically I would like to offer users the choice to 'go back' a page, and wanted to make use of the history.goBack() method to do so, however TypeScript is throwing up an error when I do, saying:

"Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'LocationDescriptor'."

Any help appreciated.

`<Link to={history.goBack()}>go back</Link>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history.goBack()` is a function that redirects you to the last visited page, stored in the history API.

The `to` property of the `<Link/>` binds to an URL (LocationDescriptor) it should redirect to. Because of this, it doesn't accept the type void.

What you could do is use the `onClick` event instead, in order to invoke the method:

```
<Link onClick={() => history.goBack()}>go back</Link>
```